# How to Make Order Requests with WP REST API to Utilize WooCommerce Lottery Plugin for Ticket Assignment?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on a Raffle Lottery WordPress site ([site link](https://afrolottogh.com/)) which runs on the **WooCommerce Lottery** and **WooCommerce Lottery Pick Number plugins**. I am trying to externally make ticket orders or purchases to the site using the **WordPress REST API** Endpoint for order requests.

I aim to have the plugin automatically assign lottery ticket numbers to orders made via the API based on the order quantity.

Could someone provide guidance or examples on how to structure order requests using the WP REST API in a way that aligns with the WooCommerce Lottery plugin's ticket assignment mechanism? Any insights or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

So I tested out the order request via the WP REST API and realized that in using the WordPress REST API Endpoint to make orders to the lottery site, *ticket selection or assigning* is not possible.

[Order Request Via WP REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1gNJ.png)

So in the image above you can see that the order is created successfully but then no ticket is assigned and when you check the lottery history tabs all purchases or orders via the API have **ZERO** as their ticket numbers.

[All ticket purchases via the API have zero as ticket numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkKUS.png)

But for ticket purchases or orders made directly on the site, everything works as it should

[Order made directly on the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH0uD.png)